# can anybody help me with my theory homework please?

Tags: analysis

let $f(x)=\sqrt x$ for $x \ge 0$

a)find a positive $\delta$ s.t. for all $x$ in the interval $[0,\infty)$ with $0 < |x-4| < \delta$ we have $|f(x)-2| < 1$

b) find a positive $\delta$ s.t. for all $x$ in the interval $[0,\infty)$ with $0 < |x-4| < \delta$ we have $|f(x)-2| < 1/10$

c) let $\epsilon$ denote an arbitrary positive number find positive $\delta$ s.t. for all $x$ in the interval $[0,\infty)$ with $0 < |x-4| < \delta$ we have $|f(x)-2| < \epsilon$.

thank you i just need help with approaching this problem. or any type of explanation im very confused.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. Find a positive $\delta$ such that what? I think you left off parts of the questions.

Comment: cameron williams i am sorry but i typed the full question out but then when i submitted it, half of the question was cut out. do you know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: (a) and (b) are the same?

Comment: Fixed.  A < sign (unless followed by a space) is thought to be an HTML tag, not a less-than symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If $|f(x)-2|<1$ then 
$$ 1<\sqrt{x}<3\quad\Rightarrow\quad 1<x<3^2=9$$
So
$$ |9-4|=5\ge\delta \ \ \land |1-4|=3\ge\delta \quad \Rightarrow \delta = 3$$